# Find the probability that the first $2$-door car is the $3rd$ one of this model delivered to this dealer this week.

Tags: probability

A certain model of a passenger car has two types: $4$-door and $2$-door cars. Suppose $60$% of the cars in this model are $4$-door cars. The two types of cars of this model will be randomly delivered to a certain dealer one by one in this week. Zachary wants to buy a $2$-door car of the model from this dealer, so he asked the dealer to notify him when the first $2$-door car is delivered.

(a) Find the probability that the first $2$-door car is the $3rd$ one of this model delivered to this dealer this week.

(b) Find the expected number of cars of this model until the first $2$-door car is delivered in this week.

Work: (a) Would it be -> Probability of $4$-door + Probability of $4$-door + Probability of $2$-door? If so how do I find the probability of $4$ and $2$-door cars?

(b) Would E(X) be $0.4$ or $2/5$? Since $P(4-door)=0.6$ and $1-0.6=0.4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We are tossing repeatedly a coin that has probability $0.4$ of landing "head" and probability $0.6$ of landing "tail."

a) We want the probability of TTH.

b) It is likely that you have been introduced to the *geometric distribution*. We want the expected number of tosses until the first head.

Comment: Would (a) be 0.6 * 0.6 * 0.4 = 0.144?

Comment: Yes, $(0.6)(0.6)(0.4)$ is right.

Comment: My textbook says for geometric dist. E(X) = 1/p this E(X) = 1/0.4?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is the number of cars delivered until (and including) the first $2$-door, then $E(X)=\frac{1}{0.4}=2.5$.